# Use zonal statistics for only some part of input shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, zonal-statistics

I have a district shapefile (districts have different size) and a raster file of precipitation (18 km grid square resolution). I want to calculate precipitation for each district which I did using zonal statistics using my district as my feature zone data, precipitation as my input raster and statistics type = mean.

I have another raster file (0.5 km resolution) which shows the distribution of cropland in my district shapefile i.e. a grid with cropland has a value of 1 and a grid without cropland has a value of 0. What I actually want to do is to calculate the mean rainfall of total cropland within a district and not for the entire district.

Could anyone suggest how to go about it?

Comment: There's a number of ways you could do this. What version and license of ArcMap do you have and do you have access to spatial analyst?

Comment: I am using Arcmap 10.2.1 and I have access to spatial analyst. But I think I have got the answer which I am posting below. let me know what you think of it.

Answer (score 2):

I used map calculator and first created a raster with following:

```
Con(cropland == 1, precipitation, NULL)
```

Then using the raster created, I did a zonal statistics with district shape file as feature and raster as input raster